# Ansible win_chocolatey says it installed Notepad++, but it doesn't?

Tags: ansible, chocolatey

`Ansible v2.11.0`

I install `Notepad++` this way

```
- name: "Install Notepad++ version {{ notepadpp_version }}"
  win_chocolatey:
    name: notepadplusplus
    version: "{{ notepadpp_version }}"
    state: present
  when: install
```

and I see this when I run my playbook, indicating it got installed.

```
TASK [exa-prereqs : Install Notepad++ version 7.9.5] ***************************
changed: [10.227.xx.xx]
```

However I don't see it installed on my host? For example, I don't see it in `Control Panel -> Uninstall or change prgram` list?

As as side question, if I specify `architecture: x64` as an option, I get

```
TASK [exa-prereqs : Install Notepad++ version 7.9.5] ***************************
fatal: [10.227.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "value of architecture must be one of: default, x86. Got no match for: x64"}
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

**Update**

I ended up using `win_package` to install `Notepad++`, but the issue with `win_chocolatey` still prevails.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like it installed it either in a per-user manner (ala portable install) or perhaps chocolatey doesn't add items to the Add Remove Software list? Did you end up checking the path where chocolatey alleged it installed it?

Comment: try notepadplusplus.install instead ...

Comment: @Spidowski can you pleasure elaborate?